# Python: Load File Contains All Unicode Characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I have a text file that has the following data:

```
<miscellaneous text for several lines>
User ID    Name
USERA      Test User 1
USERB      Test User 2
....
<more miscellaneous text for several lines>
```

I am trying to pull the user ID and Names out so I can output it into a .csv file. So I imagine the first step would be to load the file and put the contents of the text file into a string

Here is the code I have:

```
with open('FILE.txt', 'rb') as f:
    file = f.read()
    print(file)
```

but this outputs the following:
[image]

Why is it loading in the unicode NULL character? What can I do to fix this?

Also, is there a more efficient way to do this? My plan was to just do regex matches but that is not very efficient

Comment: the text file might be encoded in a different encoding. Play around with the `encoding` keyword in `open`.

Comment: That's regular ASCII zero bytes; they happen to be Unicode zeros, too (and Latin-1 zeros, etc) but that's hardly relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the file uses UTF-16. Use the correct codec and you should be fine.